Is there openapi generator for java that can generate a specific endpoint and related components from a large specification?
I have an openapi file version 3.0.1 consisting of about 1000 lines (generated automatically in a large monolithic project). I want to generate a client for java for one specific endpoint. At the same time, I don’t want to generate all the endpoints and components as this will increase the size of the final jar file too much.
I also didn’t want to manually remove all endpoints except the one needed, since the file is very large and perhaps in the future integration with other endpoints will be needed.
Is there any way to do this?
I saw this question Generate only one specific endpoint from API but it only explains how to generate a separate endpoint. But with this approach, all models are generated. I would like the necessary models to be determined themselves

Microsoft Kiota

It looks like kiota is a rather crude tool, I haven’t found how to properly connect it to the gradle build and it seems that it is not so customizable and you won’t be able to use your own RestTemplate in it.
Maybe in org.openapitools:openapi-generator-gradle-plugin you can do this?
